# JML Alternatives

Tags: java, specifications, jml

I am looking for alternative specification languages options for Java, like JML.

Does any one know any?

Thanks.

Comment: did you consider Java Path Finder?

Comment: I've used JPF on the past, but i don't think it can act as a Specification (DbC) language like JML or Cofoja, as suggested in the answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contracts for Java (http://code.google.com/p/cofoja/) is a Google project that enables you to write method contracts in Java annotations.

The framework can automatically insert the contracts as dynamic runtime checks using an offline *bytecode* rewriter.